# 2GB .KMZ file wont't open

Tags: kml, kmz, google-earth-pro

Not sure if I'm asking the right question. Never used Google Earth Pro before, but I have a 2GB KMZ file and I can't open it. Is there a way to break it down further or is there a limit to how large a kmz can be for Google Earth Pro?

Comment: I found a post on a Google Group suggesting to Add a Network Link rather than open it. The post indicated the software copies the data into your myplaces file when opened, whereas it doesn't with a link. I also saw [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975155/is-there-any-maximum-size-for-kml-files-to-open-in-google-earth) over on Stack Overflow which might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think KMZ has a size limit, but I'm pretty sure that a 2gb kmz file would be hard to manage by Google Earth/Pro. I would suggest you to clip it into different regions, so that you have smaller files.

You can open/change format/clip the KML using different softwares, the ones that I would use are Global Mapper / ArcGIS with Xtools.

But perhaps someone knows about a specific (and cheaper) tool for doing this.

M